# angular never provided resumeBootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

First of all: we already found some solutions to our problem:

- angular update -> we use the latest version of 1.4
- waitForAngular()
- window.title
- ...

But they never worked.

**To our Setup:**

We're developing an AngularJS app with version number 1.4.x.
The error appears in the E2E tests, when we try to test I18n integration.
For I18n we use angular-translate.

```
exports.config =
    seleniumServerJar: "./node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar"
    chromeDriver: "./node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver"
    capabilities:
        browserName: "chrome"
        name: "APP_NAME Selenium"
    troubleshoot: true
    framework: "jasmine2"
    rootElement: "body"
    onPrepare: ->
        global.By = global.by
        browser.manage().window().maximize()
    jasmineNodeOpts:
        showColors: true
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
        isVerbose: true
```

The weird thing is that we only get the error in about 50% of the time. Sometimes the tests pass without any error and then we have times where at least 1 test fails due to this error.

```
describe "The language", ->
    it "should be german with german URL", ->
        browser.get "/de/"
        expect( element( By.id("slogan") ).getText() ).toEqual "SLOGAN HERE!"

    it "should be preserved when a link is clicked", ->
        browser.get "/de/"
        element( By.css(".get-started a") ).click()
        expect( browser.getCurrentUrl() ).toEqual "http://localhost:3123/de/import"

        element( By.id("option-empty-table") ).click()
        expect( browser.getCurrentUrl() ).toEqual "http://localhost:3123/de/editor"

    it "should have the correct translations when a link is clicked", ->
        browser.get "/de/"

        element( By.css(".get-started a") ).click()
        expect( element( By.css("#option-empty-table a h3") ).getText() ).toEqual "SOME STRING"
```

We start the tests with Gulp. Here's the gulp task:

```
gulp.task "e2e",
    "Runs all e2e tests.",
    [
        "run"
    ],
    ->
        gulp.src E2E_FILES
        .pipe protractor
            configFile: "./protractor.config.coffee"
            args: [
                "--baseUrl"
                BASEURL
            ]
```

The BASEURL variable is "http://localhost:3123"

Last but not least here is the "run" task from gulp:

```
gulp.task "run", "Serves the App.",
    [
        "build"
    ],
    ->
        browserSync.init
            server:
                baseDir: BUILD.dirs.out
                index: "/statics/master.html"
                middleware: [modRewrite(['!\\.\\w+$ /statics/master.html [L]'])]
            open: false
            port: 3123
            ui:
                port: 3124
                weinre: 3125
            logLevel: "info"
            notify: false
            logPrefix: "SOME_PREFIX"
```

Has anybody ever had such a strange behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What error? You haven't really explained what the problem is...

Comment: It's in the title. I thought it would be clear, because some people already had this problem. But the full error message is: "Failed: Angular could not be found on the page http://localhost:3123/de/ : angular never provided resumeBootstrap"

Comment: @AndrewFerrier do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't figured this out yet either, but I am also using browserSync, using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js, and latest protractor...Maybe we're seeing something new?

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:**

Add `scrollRestoreTechnique: 'cookie'` to your browsersync config.

**Long answer:**

Browsersync (>=2.7.11) [restores your scroll position](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-scrollRestoreTechnique) when it refreshes and it stores that information in one of two places - `window.name` (the default) or a cookie.

Unfortunately, Protractor uses an Angular feature called [Deferred Bootstrap](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/guide/bootstrap) that uses `window.name` and conflicts with BrowserSync. From the AngularJS Docs:

> This feature enables tools like Batarang and test runners to hook into angular's bootstrap process and sneak in more modules into the DI registry which can replace or augment DI services for the purpose of instrumentation or mocking out heavy dependencies.
>
> If window.name contains prefix NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP! when angular.bootstrap is called, the bootstrap process will be paused until angular.resumeBootstrap() is called.

If Browsersync overwrites that `window.name` value before it gets caught by Angular, Angular will not defer its Bootstrap and Protractor will subsequently not be able to find the `resumeBootstrap` function because it won't exist.

Telling Browsersync to use a cookie instead of window.name resolves the conflict.

Comment: This sounds logical, but unfortunately it didn't fix my problem. I inserted the line after the logPrefix line as it can be seen above. Furthermore I updated to protractor 2.47.1. Do I have to set NG_DEFER_BOOTSTRAP! manually? Or do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Benjamin Kitt: worked for me..!! Excellent observation... :)